# ScalaJ vs Vertx - Same http call different results

Tags: scala, http, networking, slick, vert.x

I have two pieces of scala code to upload a file to a server. The ScalaJ version works, the Vertx version does not. Can someone tell me how to determine the actual outgoing calls? Other Vertx calls (without file uploads) are working fine.

ScalaJ (working i.e. the server responds with 200)

```
val bytes: Array[Byte] = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("myfile.pdf"))

Http(myurl)
  .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate")
  .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
  .header("x-client-id", CLIENT_ID)
  .header("x-client-secret", CLIENT_SECRET)
  .header("Authorization" , "Bearer " + mytoken)
  .postMulti(MultiPart("registrationFormPDF", "name.pdf", "application/pdf", bytes))
  .asString
```

Vertx (not working i.e. the server responds with 500)

```
val request = client.requestAbs(HttpMethod.POST, myurl)
  .putHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate")
  .putHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
  .putHeader("x-client-id", CLIENT_ID)
  .putHeader("x-client-secret", CLIENT_SECRET)
  .putHeader("Authorization" , "Bearer " + mytoken)
  .ssl(true)
  .timeout(TIMEOUT)

val bytes: Array[Byte] = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("myfile.pdf"))
val buffer = Buffer.buffer(bytes)

val multiPartForm = MultipartForm.create()
  .binaryFileUpload("registrationFormPDF", "name.pdf", buffer, "application/pdf")

val promise = Promise[MyResponse]()

request.sendMultipartForm(multiPartForm.get, responseHandler(_, promise))
```

Comment: What is the 500 error you are getting?

Comment: It's coming from the Server the file has to be uploaded to (no description other than 500). But I cannot change anything about that, I'd like to know how to figure out the actual outgoing call

Comment: You can use wireshark to see the difference between two requests.